# Compare Two Files using Unix Commands and Find the common items

Tags: unix, awk, rtf, text-processing

I have two files which have some information regarding an IP address. I need to compare these files, then I need to create a new file with only the items which New.txt and Old.txt have in common. I need to run it as a batch so that's why I need to know the unix commands to automate this process.

Nevertheless, important fact would be that though there may be same description in both files, the starting number may be different.

For eg: 
New.txt

```
\subsubsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 123.123.123.123}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{Red}High & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (July 2014 CPU) & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?7de2f8eb}{$\Rightarrow$}   \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{Red}High & Oracle GlassFish Server Unspecified Vulnerability (January 2015 CPU) & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?c02f1515}{$\Rightarrow$}   \\ \hline
     3  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Apache HTTP Server httpOnly Cookie Information Disclosure  & \href{http://fd.the-wildcat.de/apache\_e36a9cf46c.php}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     4  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods Allowed  & \href{http://www.cgisecurity.com/whitehat-mirror/WH-WhitePaper\_XST\_ebook.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     5  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 / 3.1.2 / Enterprise 2.1.1 DoS  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?1cef09be}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     6  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2013 CPU)  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?4ea424bc}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     7  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Version 2 and 3 Protocol Detection  & \href{http://www.schneier.com/paper-ssl.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     8  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSLv3 Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption Vulnerability (POODLE)  & \href{https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/10/14/poodle.html}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     9  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?217a3666}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
    10  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & Web Server Uses Basic Authentication Without HTTPS  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=34850}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Old.txt

```
\subsubsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 123.123.123.123}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{Red}High & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (July 2014 CPU) & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?7de2f8eb}{$\Rightarrow$}   \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Apache HTTP Server httpOnly Cookie Information Disclosure  & \href{http://fd.the-wildcat.de/apache\_e36a9cf46c.php}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     3  & \celcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods Allowed  & \href{http://www.cgisecurity.com/whitehat-mirror/WH-WhitePaper\_XST\_ebook.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     4  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 / 3.1.2 / Enterprise 2.1.1 DoS  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?1cef09be}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     5  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2013 CPU)  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?4ea424bc}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     6  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & PHP expose\_php Information Disclosure  & \href{http://www.0php.com/php\_easter\_egg.php}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline         7 & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?217a3666}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     8  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & Web Server Uses Basic Authentication Without HTTPS  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=34850}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     9  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & Web Server Uses Plain Text Authentication Forms  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=26194}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

And finally compare the files and print only the common items
compare.txt

```
\subsubsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 123.123.123.123}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{Red}High & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (July 2014 CPU) & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?7de2f8eb}{$\Rightarrow$}   \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Apache HTTP Server httpOnly Cookie Information Disclosure  & \href{http://fd.the-wildcat.de/apache\_e36a9cf46c.php}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     3  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods Allowed  & \href{http://www.cgisecurity.com/whitehat-mirror/WH-WhitePaper\_XST\_ebook.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     4  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 / 3.1.2 / Enterprise 2.1.1 DoS  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?1cef09be}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     5  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & Oracle GlassFish Server Multiple Vulnerabilities (October 2013 CPU)  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?4ea424bc}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     6  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?217a3666}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
    7   & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & Web Server Uses Basic Authentication Without HTTPS  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=34850}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `1.` If the result must include items that have the same IP address in both files, why do you include the first 4 and last 2 lines in compare.txt that don't even have an IP address? `2.` Do you want in the result the complete lines from Old.txt file? It wouldn't be better to include just the IP addresses? `3.` The "batch-file" tag refers to a Windows .BATch file (you may review the tag description). If you want not a .BAT file solution, but a Unix one, please remove this tag; otherwise confirm that you want a Windows .BAT file (and remove the "unix" tag).

Answer (score 0):

`comm -12 Old.txt New.txt > common.txt`